# Why are edge betweenness and weighted edge betweenness results exactly the same?

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory

I have two graphs (`g1` & `g2`) created from adjacency matrices (`mtx1` & `mtx2`), one is unweighted (`g1`) the other is weighted (`g2`), I am calculating edge betweenness for the two graphs.

My understanding was that by using `edge_betweenness(g, weights = E(g)$weight)` I could incorporate edge weights into the calculation of edge betweenness for the weighted graph, but when I do this I get the exact same result for my weighted and unweighted graphs.

Why does adding weights to the calculation of edge betweenness not change the resulting scores?

Consider the following example

```
library(igraph)

# create non-weighted adjacency matrix (mtx1) and a weighted matrix (mtx2)        
mtx1 <- matrix(c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0), ncol = 5)
mtx2 <- matrix(c(0,2,0,0,0,1,0,2,2,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0), ncol = 5)

# convert to igraph objects
g1 <- graph.adjacency(mtx1)
g2 <- graph.adjacency(mtx2, weighted = TRUE)

# calculate edge betweenness for the two graphs 
edge_betweenness(g1)
[1] 4 4 6 4 6 4 4 4

edge_betweenness(g2, weights = E(g2)$weight)
[1] 4 4 6 4 6 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of edge_betweeness of a vertex is the *number* of shortest paths 
going through that vertex. For both g1 and g2, the shortest path between any two nodes is the same. Because of your weights, the *lengths* of those paths are not the same, but the sequence of edges is the same.

If you wish to see an example where the weighted graph gives different betweeness,  you must construct an example where the weight changes 
whether or not something is a shortest path.

Here is an example in the spirit of yours.

```
mtx3 <- matrix(c(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0), ncol=4)
mtx4 <- matrix(c(0,2,1,0,2,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0), ncol=4)
g3 <- graph.adjacency(mtx3)
g4 <- graph.adjacency(mtx4, weighted = TRUE)

edge_betweenness(g3)
[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
edge_betweenness(g4, weights = E(g4)$weight)
[1] 1 2 1 2 2 3 2 3
```

Notice that the path 1->2->4  is a shortest path for g3, but not for g4.

Comment: Ahh thank you for that explanation, makes sense! looks like a need a different metric then. Cheers.